# UserControl in windows forms with custom actions

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a user control windows forms which has a picture box and label. I will add this to my form where ever need and on each form submit I would like to activate the load user control and show busy indicator along with custom message which I will pass from my each form. The picture box is still showing instead of visibility set to false. Also the label text I couldn't change. Here is the code

On my form1 load I write as follows

```
UserControl1 u = new UserControl1();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        u.Hide();
        HideShowControl();

    }

    private void HideShowControl(bool isVisible = false)
    {
        foreach (var control in u.Controls)
        {
            if (control is Panel)
            {

                ((Panel)control).Visible = isVisible;

                HideChildren((Panel)control, isVisible);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HideChildren(Panel control, bool isVisible = false)
    {
        foreach (var c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is PictureBox)
            {
                ((PictureBox)c).Visible = isVisible;

            }
            if (c is Label)
            {
                ((Label)c).Visible = isVisible;

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in my drive

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zpH3uBrbaHeYHEKg3TmZ5DhijiUMDflY

[image]

Comment: we need to know whether the controls that are still visible are inside other controls, like groupbox or so.

Comment: When I set visible to false in the user control on any action it is not displaying that indicator attached the image on how it show

Comment: How about showing/hiding the UserControl itself instead of iterating through its controls? If you have a good reason to do so, then how about placing the label and the picture box in a panel then you just need to toggle the visibility of this panel? Good luck.

Comment: No luck either.